# Build a table with row and column spans for my JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, node.js

I wanted to achieve similar result as shown in below image

**Expected result:**

[image]

what I'm expecting is if it is done using **recursion** most welcome

I will recieve huge json from backend with `user_data`  having 50 `objects`

**Note**:recursive approach is most welcome

here is what I have tried:

```js
var data = [{
  "user_data": [{
    "amount": 2550,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 2550,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }],
  "name": "hulk"
}, {
  "user_data": [ {
    "amount": 2125,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 1700,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 1700,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 2125,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }],
  "name": "gomu"
}];

var tableStr = '';
data.forEach((obj) => {
   var userData = obj.user_data;
   userData.forEach((o) => {
      tableStr += '<tr rowspan="'+userData.length+'"><td>'+o.time1+'</td><td>'+o.time2+'</td><td>'+o.amount+'</td></tr>';
   });
});

$('#user').html(tableStr);
```

```css
table { 
       border-collapse: collapse;
   }

td {
    padding: 20px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="user">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>User Name</th>
          <th>Time 1</th>
          <th>Time 2</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There's no need for recursion for this. You can do it by iterating the "user_data" array.

Comment: ok thanks for suggestion , **but result is not coming as expected with total**  please help me

Comment: because you didn't implement total functionality

Comment: actually i don't know i'm still in learning phase

Comment: Note (in my answer below) how a couple of extra calculations allows you to change the amount of fields in "user_data" and still format the table correctly. No need for recursion.

Comment: dear answerer please note rowspan can be determined by `user_data.length` i'm expecting this to be dynamic not hardcoded. because in real scenario it can vary each time

Comment: I adjusted my answer to include dynamic "user_data" fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with some slight modifications to your code.  You need to add the name with a colspan, then in the obj loop, add a total at the end.  Then when updating your table, only set the html for the tbody element.  Like below

```js
var data = [{
  "user_data": [{
    "amount": 2550,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 2550,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }],
  "name": "hulk"
}, {
  "user_data": [ {
    "amount": 2125,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 1700,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 1700,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 2125,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }],
  "name": "gomu"
}];

var tableStr = '';
data.forEach((obj) => {
    var userData = obj.user_data;
    var total = 0;
   
    userData.forEach((o, index) => {
      tableStr += '<tr>' + (index == 0 ? '<td rowspan="' + userData.length + '">' + obj.name + '</td>' : '') + '<td>'+o.time1+'</td><td>'+o.time2+'</td><td>'+o.amount+'</td></tr>';
       total += o.amount;
   });
   tableStr += '<tr><td colspan="3">Total</td><td>' + total + '</td></tr>';
});
$('#user tbody').html(tableStr);
```

```css
table { 
       border-collapse: collapse;
   }

td {
    padding: 20px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="user">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>User Name</th>
          <th>Time 1</th>
          <th>Time 2</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: (Minor nitpick: instead of the `isFirst` variable, I might suggest `forEach((o, index)=>{}` and then check `index===0`).  Either way works of course, but the index param is a bit tidier.)

Comment: sorry to ask you, you have hardcoded `colspan="3"` but my data will be dynamic from server this is just a sample `data`

Comment: By "data will be dynamic" do you mean you may have a variable number of "time" columns? That would have been useful information to include in the question.....

Comment: @skBangalore I hardcoded that to the number of columns you specified in your thead.  If columns is dynamic, you will need more work on this.

Comment: @DanielBeck You are correct, index is the better route, adjusted my answer.

Comment: The only extra step is counting the keys in the "user_data" object and replacing the hardcoded 3 in the total row.

Comment: @Niche That would require more than just that as the headers would need to be expanded to as well.

Comment: @bhmahler, can you please help me with the more work  

**you said:** I hardcoded that to the number of columns you specified in your thead. If columns is dynamic, you will need more work on this

Comment: @bhmahler I see what you mean. The cells would have to be dynamically created as well, since this only works for _those specific fields_.

Comment: That requires substantially more work.  If your user_data properties are variable, than this will need to be made completely dynamic.  You will need to get all possible columns for every type, then build your rows and check each entry to ensure it has the property etc.

Comment: Still, definitely, no recursion though

Comment: @skBangalore To elaborate more on the hardcoded rowspan, that is not for the name (which is dynamic based on the number of entries), that is for the Total which is based on your 4 column fixed layout in this implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather not build a string. Instead use jQuery DOM functions to generate the table:

```js
var data = [{
  "user_data": [{
    "amount": 2550,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 2550,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }],
  "name": "hulk"
}, {
  "user_data": [{
    "amount": 2125,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 1700,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 1700,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 2125,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }],
  "name": "gomu"
}];

data.forEach(function(row) {
  var user0 = row.user_data[0];
  var users = row.user_data.slice(1);
  var total = 0;

  // first row of the group contains user name and first user_data
  total += user0.amount;
  var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
  $("<td></td>").attr("rowspan", 1 + users.length).text(row.name).appendTo($tr);
  $("<td></td>").text(user0.time1).appendTo($tr);
  $("<td></td>").text(user0.time2).appendTo($tr);
  $("<td></td>").text(user0.amount).appendTo($tr);
  $tr.appendTo("#user > tbody");


  // create additional rows for remaining user_data
  users.forEach(function(user) {
    total += user.amount;
    var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    $("<td></td>").text(user.time1).appendTo($tr);
    $("<td></td>").text(user.time2).appendTo($tr);
    $("<td></td>").text(user.amount).appendTo($tr);
    $tr.appendTo("#user > tbody");
  });

  // total was calculated above
  $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
  $("<td colspan=3>Total</td>").appendTo($tr);
  $("<td></td>").text(total).appendTo($tr);
  $tr.appendTo("#user > tbody");
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="user">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User Name</th>
      <th>Time 1</th>
      <th>Time 2</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The advantage to building a string is that it doesn't cause the browser to have to reflow the window every time you modify the DOM.

Comment: The browser does not necessarily reflow after executing each line of JavaScript. But if you're worried, just append all rows to the table at the end in one go. This is roughly the same as appending a string except you dont have to worry about broken HTML, escaping characters like `<` and `&`.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use recursion for your case. Please take a look the below script and read the comment:

```js
var data = [{
  "user_data": [{
    "amount": 2550,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 2550,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }],
  "name": "hulk"
}, {
  "user_data": [ {
    "amount": 2125,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 1700,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 1700,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }, {
    "amount": 2125,
    "time1": "2017/04/05",
    "time2": "2017/04/06"
  }],
  "name": "gomu"
}];

for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  var rows = data[i].user_data.length;
  var html = '';
  var total = 0;
  
  // start rendering user_data
  for (r=0; r<rows; r++) {

    html += '<tr>';
    if (r == 0) { // render for first row of user data only
      html += '<td rowspan="'+rows+'">'+data[i].name+'</td>';
    }
    html += '<td>'+data[i].user_data[r].time1+'</td>';
    html += '<td>'+data[i].user_data[r].time2+'</td>';
    html += '<td>'+data[i].user_data[r].amount+'</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    total += data[i].user_data[r].amount;
    
  }

  // render total row
  html += '<tr><td colspan="3">Total:</td><td>'+total+'</td></tr>';

  // append user_data into the table
  $('table#user tbody').append(html);
}
```

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="user">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>User Name</th>
          <th>Time 1</th>
          <th>Time 2</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the total calculation logic in your iteration. I added in some extra formatting for the rowspan and colspan in the total row:

```
data.forEach((obj) => {
    var userData = obj.user_data;
    var rowTotal = 0;
    var rowsize;
    tableStr += '<tr><td rowspan="'userData.length'">obj.name</td>
    userData.forEach((o, index) => {
        if(index > 0) {
            tableStr += '<tr>'
        } else {
            rowsize = Object.keys(o).length;
        }
        Object.values(o).forEach((value) => {
            tableStr += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
        });
        rowTotal += o.amount;
        tableStr += '</tr>';
    });
    tableStr += '<tr><td colspan="' + rowsize + '">Total</td><td>'+rowTotal+'</td></tr>'
});
```

**Note**: This snippet assumes the "user_data" object always has an "amount" value that accumulates for the total.